# Sync Multiple Slick sliders together

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

I'm working with Slick Slider and would like to sync 3 sliders together.

I have a JSfiddle of my problem here:

https://jsfiddle.net/rk0tuoy7/1/

HTML:

```
<section class="slider">
    <div>slide1</div>
    <div>slide2</div>
    <div>slide3</div>
    <div>slide4</div>
    <div>slide5</div>
    <div>slide6</div>
</section>

<section class="slider2">
    <div>slide1</div>
    <div>slide2</div>
    <div>slide3</div>
    <div>slide4</div>
    <div>slide5</div>
    <div>slide6</div>
</section>

<section class="slider3">
    <div>slide1</div>
    <div>slide2</div>
    <div>slide3</div>
    <div>slide4</div>
    <div>slide5</div>
    <div>slide6</div>
</section>
```

JS:

```
$(".slider").slick({});
$(".slider2").slick({ asNavFor: '.slider' });
$(".slider3").slick({ asNavFor: '.slider2' });
```

I can get slider 1 to sync with slider 2, and I can get slider 2 to sync with slider 3, but I can't get all 3 working together. Is there a way I could get this to work?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How about something like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/rk0tuoy7/2/

HTML:

```
<section class="slider slider1">
    <div>slide1</div>
    <div>slide2</div>
    <div>slide3</div>
    <div>slide4</div>
    <div>slide5</div>
    <div>slide6</div>
</section>

<section class="slider slider2">
    <div>slide1</div>
    <div>slide2</div>
    <div>slide3</div>
    <div>slide4</div>
    <div>slide5</div>
    <div>slide6</div>
</section>

<section class="slider slider3">
    <div>slide1</div>
    <div>slide2</div>
    <div>slide3</div>
    <div>slide4</div>
    <div>slide5</div>
    <div>slide6</div>
</section>
```

JS:

```
$(".slider").slick({ asNavFor: '.slider' });
```

Now all the sliders have both a generic `slider` class, as well as a numbered slider class if you need to do different things to them at some other time.

Comment: How can i use this while having different settings for each slider?

Comment: You may want to ask that as a new question.

Comment: @RoeeYossef I need this answer as well, I need second slider to have fading effects and no arrows

Comment: Just did - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41870850/multiple-slick-sliders-with-different-settings @jaybee

Answer (score 3):

Just use multiple classes in the asNavFor. For example:

```
asNavFor: $('.slider, .slider2, .slider3')
```